# Facebook app invite notification received but not showing message

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-app-requests

I successfully implemented Facebook app invites and tested it with 2 different test users. The only problem is that another test user receives an app invite notification but when I click on the notification then nothing is showed to me. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I am testing this on Facebook lite, version of android sdk is :4.17.0

Does this have do anything with Facebook App Centre? Why is this happening? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check if application "S" is installed on that device.. or you have given correct applinkurl.

Comment: Yes, it is installed and app link is also correct, that's the test user is receiving the notification